# What is a Typical View for iPhone Info Button Display?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview, uibutton

I added an info button in the bottom right corner of the screen in my project. What is a common view to display when this button is pressed? I basically want general app and developer information to be shown but I also want to be able to add a button or two in the future to say bring the user to my app store page and such. UIAlertView isn't quite what I had in mind. I imagined a sort of gray semi-translucent box popping up over the main view.

My project currently only has one view controller. My app basically takes in video and processes it so I never leave that main view. This is how I added the button:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    infoButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeInfoDark];
    [infoButton addTarget:self 
                   action:@selector(infoButtonAction:)
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    infoButton.frame = CGRectMake(280.0, 420.0, 20.0, 20.0);
    [self.view addSubview:infoButton];
}

- (IBAction)infoButtonAction:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"info clicked");
   // What should I add here?
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The info button usually presents a modal view controller with a horizontal flip transition. See the Weather and Stocks apps, and Xcode's "Utility Application" project template.

**Edit: Sample code**

You'd create a new subclass of `UIViewController` to display your information. To present it in code (as opposed to storyboard segues) you'd do this:

```
- (IBAction)infoButtonAction:(id)sender
{
    InfoViewController *infoViewController = [[InfoViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"InfoViewController" bundle:nil];
    infoViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
    [self presentViewController:infoViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Then you could hook up a done button to dismiss it:

```
- (IBAction)doneButtonTapped:(id)sender
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That is pretty much exactly what I found in this youtube tutorial http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zzay_bHVBS0.